# How do you insert data into complex data type “Struct” in Hive 2

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

This is the structure of the table

```
CREATE TABLE warehouse (
 time timestamp, 
 person struct<id : int, name: string, organization : string>, 
 activity struct<id : int, name: string>, 
 case struct<id : int, name: string, organization : string>
);
```

The table is created without problems, the problem is how to insert data into that table. I was trying something like this but it does not work

```
INSERT INTO TABLE warehouse VALUES('2018-05-31'),
SELECT NAMED_STRUCT('id', 1, 'name', 'Alex', 'organization', 'CITI') AS person,
SELECT NAMED_STRUCT('id', 1, 'name', 'Buy') AS activity,
SELECT NAMED_STRUCT('id', 1, 'name', 'Gold', 'organization', 'London') AS case
FROM case
```

The case, activity and person tables already exist and have the structure shown in the select.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please edit your post to also provide the error message that you receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot use the NAMED_STRUCT in an INSERT statement with VALUES  (even more, you cannot use any udfs inserting with values) . This is a workaround working example.

```
CREATE TABLE warehouse (
 time timestamp, 
 person struct<id : int, name: string, organization : string>, 
 activity struct<id : int, name: string>, 
 `case` struct<id : int, name: string, organization : string>
);


INSERT INTO TABLE warehouse
select 
'2018-05-31',
NAMED_STRUCT('id', 1, 'name', 'Alex', 'organization', 'CITI'),
NAMED_STRUCT('id', 1, 'name', 'Buy'),
NAMED_STRUCT('id', 1, 'name', 'Gold', 'organization', 'London') 
FROM (
select '1'
) t 
;
```