# Correct usage of a struct in Hive

Tags: sql, arrays, struct, hive, hiveql

I want to use a struct which contains a string and an array. The string represents the name of a service, while the array lists the company ids which carry out that service.

I know that I can create and insert into a struct look so:

```
CREATE TABLE struct_test
(
 property_id INT,
 service STRUCT<
                type: STRING
               ,provider: ARRAY<INT>
               >
);

INSERT INTO TABLE struct_test 
    SELECT 989, NAMED_STRUCT('type','Cleaning','provider', ARRAY(587, 887)) AS address 
    FROM tmp LIMIT 1;
```

This gives me the following:

```
>{"type":"Cleaning","provider":[587,887]}
```

However, I want to account for multiple service types on the same property. How could I have more than one type in my `service` struct?

Ideally, I would want to achieve something similar to the below:

> {"type":"Cleaning","provider":[587,887]}, {"type":"Pricing","provider":[932]}, {"type":"Security","provider":[187,577,946]}

This way I can store multiple services in the column and the providers who provide that service. Can this model be achieved using a struct?

Comment: what's there in your tmp table?

Comment: @vikrantrana it is a dummy table only used for the purpose of inserting, as you cannot insert using values (xxx, xxx, xxx). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631068/how-do-you-insert-data-into-complex-data-type-struct-in-hive-2

Comment: I get that. then how does it different from statement as SELECT 989, NAMED_STRUCT('type','Cleaning','provider', ARRAY(587, 887)) AS address;   where will we get the values for Security and pricing etc?

Comment: @vikrantrana for now they can be hardcoded into the `insert` as I am trying to see if this model is achievable with a struct

Comment: this achievable with array<struct<type: STRING, provider: ARRAY<INT>>>

Comment: @leftjoin would you be able to provide an example in an answer?

Comment: Please see the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This achievable with `array<struct<type: STRING, provider: ARRAY<INT>>>`

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE struct_test
(
 property_id INT,
 service array<STRUCT<
                type: STRING
               ,provider: ARRAY<INT>
               >>
);
```

Insert data:

```
with 
test_data as(
    SELECT 989 property_id, array(NAMED_STRUCT('type','Cleaning','provider', ARRAY(587, 887)),
                      NAMED_STRUCT('type','Pricing','provider', ARRAY(932))
                      ) as service
)

INSERT INTO TABLE struct_test 
select * from test_data;
```

Check data:

```
select t.property_id, t.service from struct_test t;
```

Result:

```
OK
property_id     service
989     [{"type":"Cleaning","provider":[587,887]},{"type":"Pricing","provider":[932]}]
Time taken: 0.064 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

And if you want collect array of structs in the select rather than hardcoded values, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48175749/2700344

For such a complex data type you definitely need [brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Downloads) library